# What is the proper method to format dates?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have some `DateTime`s in my model.  I only want to extract the date in a particular view.

By formatting the data in my view instead of my model, I can give other views the flexibility to use `DateTime` or just `Date`.

How can I go about formatting my `DateTime` in a View?

Comment: Why wouldn't you format it the same way as you would in any other kind of program? What's special about it being in MVC?

Comment: @John Saunders - MVC should not have much C# in the view.  There's a tendency to use HTML helper methods and Extension Methods.  These are more elegant.

Comment: Brian: so the question isn't so much about formatting in MVC, but in an MVC view?

Comment: @John Saunders - Where and how to format arbitrary Model data in the MVC pattern with minimal disturbance of the default model data format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@(String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", Model.dt));
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do

```
dateTime.ToShortDateString();
```

Or

```
dateTime.ToString("{0:d}");
```

Or

```
dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing something but it would just be

```
Model.DateTimeProperty.ToString("mm/dd/yyy")
```

Or whatever other format you want to use. Same as formatting it anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use -

```
DateTime date= DateTime.Now; 
string onlyDate=date.ToShortDateString();
```